# Trouble getting Redux Thunk to work

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm learning Redux and have come across an issue when trying to use redux-thunk. I'm using Redux for a Chrome extension i'm building using [this](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux) . Here is the setup I have at the moment:

**Index.js:**

```
import {applyMiddleware,createStore} from 'redux';
import combineReducers from './reducers/index';
import {wrapStore} from 'react-chrome-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);
const store = createStore(combineReducers,{}, middleware);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState().lastAction);
});

wrapStore(store, {
  portName: 'example'
});
```

**reducers/index.js:**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import userAuthReducer from './userAuthReducer';
import manageTeamsReducer from './manageTeamsReducer';

function lastAction(state = null, action) {
  return action;
}

export default combineReducers({
  lastAction,userAuthReducer,manageTeamsReducer
});
```

**manageTeamsReducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  userTeams: []
};

const manageTeamsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_TEAMS': {
      const newState = Object.assign(state, {
        userTeams:action.teams
      });
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default manageTeamsReducer;
```

**actions.js**

```
export const getUserTeams = () => {

// if I uncomment the below block and make it a normal action then it works as desired
/*  return {
        type: "SET_USER_TEAMS",
        teams:[{_id:"asd",name:"fwewef"}]       
    }*/

//this action below is the thunk action that currently does not work
 return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_USER_TEAMS",
                teams:[{_id:"asd",name:"fwewef"}]
      });
  };
};
```

Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as authActions from '../../../../../../event/src/actions/userAuthActions';
import * as teamActions from '../../../../../../event/src/actions/manageTeams';

var cookies = require('browser-cookies');

class Login extends Component {

login(event) {
  this.props.actions.authActions.setUserLoggedInState(true)
  this.props.actions.teamActions.getUserTeams()     
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-par">
                <div onClick={this.login.bind(this)}></div>             
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
        manageTeamsReducer:state.manageTeamsReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
        actions:{
            authActions: bindActionCreators(authActions,dispatch),
            teamActions: bindActionCreators(teamActions,dispatch)
    }}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

What should happen is when `this.login` function is triggered on click in the component it should fire off the two actions. The first action: `this.props.actions.authActions.setUserLoggedInState(true)` fires off no problem and does exactly what it should. This is because it's a regular Redux action that simply returns an object with a type and payload.

The second action however needs to be a Thunk and no matter how I re-arrange my code with examples I find online I can't seem to get it to work. If I uncomment the first return statement in actions.js and comment out the second return statement hence making it a regular action then it works fine but I need to be able to use Thunk.

Not sure if anyone can spot if i've maybe setup Redux-Thunk wrong or anything else?

Note: there's a chance it there could be a different way to implement it due to the react-chrome-redux package i'm using but I have seen people who use the same package like [here](https://github.com/ihenvyr/react-chrome-extension) and upon installing their package it seems they've managed to make it work fine - I can't however see why mine won't work.

**EDIT**

I have implemented the aliases as per Sidney's recommendation as follows:

**Index.js:**

```
import {applyMiddleware,createStore} from 'redux';
import combineReducers from './reducers/index';
import {wrapStore,alias} from 'react-chrome-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import aliases from './aliases/aliases';

const middlewares = applyMiddleware([alias(aliases), thunk]);
const store = createStore(combineReducers,{}, middlewares);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState().lastAction);
});

wrapStore(store, {
  portName: 'example'
});
```

**Aliases.js**

```
const getUserTeams = (orginalAction) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_USER_TEAMS_RESOLVED",
                teams:[{_id:"asd",name:"it worked!"}]   
      });
  };
};

export default {
  'SET_USER_TEAMS': getUserTeams // the action to proxy and the new action to call
};
```

**actions.js**

```
export const getUserTeams = () => {
    return {
        type: "SET_USER_TEAMS",
        teams:[]        
    }
};
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  userTeams: []
};

const manageTeamsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_TEAMS_RESOLVED': {
      const newState = Object.assign(state, {
        userTeams:action.teams
      });
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default manageTeamsReducer;
```

**Component**

There is nothing changed in the component as my understanding is I should still be dispatching the same action:

```
this.props.actions.teamActions.getUserTeams()
```

It's still not returning me the new object with "it worked!" as the payload in the app. I've tried to follow the example and documentation as best I can. Not sure if i've missed out anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [alias](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/wiki/Advanced-Usage#alias), which is provided by the react-chrome-redux library.

The problem you're having right now is that the asynchronous action returns a function, which can't be sent to the background page over the messaging protocol. Instead, you'd dispatch a normal object-action, which is defined in an alias as a thunk.

[The boilerplate repo that you linked](https://github.com/ihenvyr/react-chrome-extension) has an example of how to set up and use aliases.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, i've updated my code to include Aliases (above) but still can't get it to hijack the original action...

Comment: In your Component file, clicking the inner <div> should trigger the alias. Maybe it does, but I don't see any place that you render the `userTeams` from the state.

Comment: I've dumbed down the component for posting it on here but the component maps over the userTeams array if it's successful. I also see the SET_USER_TEAMS action being fired off instead of the SET_USER_TEAMS_RESOLVED (in the console) which tells me its not hijacking it properly

Comment: Do you have your code in a public repo? Post a link, if possible. I'll need to see your full code to provide any more help.